# Change distance between edges in dot

Tags: graphviz, dot

Is there a way to control the spacing between edges in dot, similar to the `nodesep` attribute in the other graphviz layout engines? I would like to keep using `dot` as the layout engine.

By edges I mean either multi-edges or multi-coloured edges, like in the following example. I would like to decrease the space between the `a->b` edges or increase the space between the `c->d` edges.

```
digraph G {
  nodesep = "0.15"
  a -> b [dir=none color="red"]
  a -> b [dir=none color="blue"]
  a -> b [dir=none color="green"]
  
  c -> d [dir=none color="green:red:blue"]
}
```

[image: graph]

In dot, the `nodesep` attribute does not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to add transparent edges. That way, this solution works regardless of background colour. Since the edges are transparent, overlap is not a problem and all the coloured edges have the same width.

```
digraph G {
  c -> d [
    dir=none
    penwidth=5
    color="red:transparent:transparent:green:transparent:transparent:blue"
  ]
}
```

Produces:

[image: graph]

This works for an arbitrary number of edges, and the spacing can be controlled by changing the number of transparent edges between each coloured edge.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a white background, add white (invisible) lines to change the apparent spacing:

```
digraph G {
  nodesep = "0.15"
  
  c -> d [dir=none color="green:white:white:white:red:white:white:white:blue"]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: The reason I want to separate the edges is to make them thicker without overlapping. Unfortunately, this solution doesn't let me do that

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in that code, only one leg is thicker (penwidth).
So, this solution used ports:

```
digraph G {
 // nodesep = "0.15"
 splines=false
 edge[penwidth=7]
  a:sw -> b:nw [dir=none color="red"]
  a -> b [dir=none color="blue"]
  a:se -> b:ne [dir=none color="green"]
  
  c -> d [dir=none color="green:white:white:white:red:white:white:white:blue"]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: `splines=false` is probably the closest thing to what I want, though I don't want to mess with manually selecting ports. The "bug" is that the spacing of multicolour edges is constant, so thick edges get drawn over each other. That's why only the rightmost edge appears to have the correct thickness